# Modules not found when changing the order of imports. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, import, node-modules

I'm building a seeder (seeder.js) for an E-comm app and I stored some dummy data in two files: products.js and users.js (Some products and three users I want to insert into the database). I created a script called "data:import" which runs the seeder.js script.

When I run "npm run data:import" into my terminal I get an error that says that it cannot find the module "../users". Now here is the strange part: When I move the import of '../products.js' ABOVE the "../users" import and then run again the data:import script, it says that it cannot find the "../products.js"

Why is this happening? I get no errors when I reference both users and products in this seeder file.

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import colors from "colors";
import users from "./data/users";
import products from "./data/products";
import User from "./models/userModel";
import Product from "./models/productModel";
import Order from "./models/orderModel";
import connectDB from "./config/db";

dotenv.config();

connectDB();

const importData = async () => {
  try {
    await Order.deleteMany();
    await Product.deleteMany();
    await User.deleteMany();

    const createUsers = await User.insertMany(users);
    const adminUser = createUsers[0]._id;
    const sampleProducts = products.map((product) => {
      return { ...product, user: adminUser };
    });

    await Product.insertMany(sampleProducts);

    console.log("Data imported".green.inverse);
    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`${error}`.red.inverse);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

const destroyData = async () => {
  try {
    await Order.deleteMany();
    await Product.deleteMany();
    await User.deleteMany();

    console.log("Data destroyed".red.inverse);
    process.exit();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`${error}`.error.inverse);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

if (process.argv[2] === "-d") {
  destroyData();
} else {
  importData();
}
```